# Install openCV without build the project

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, ubuntu

I want to install OpenCV for use it in Python. I found a tutorial how to install it at: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/. But I have a limited spaces, around 3Gb so. I can't compile the project. How can I install OpenCV in this case? I use Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

You can install the [conda package manager](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/conda) via `pip install conda`and [install opencv3](https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3) via `conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv3`

Another option is to use the pre-compiled Windows binaries from: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and install them with `pip` (this just works for Windows).